# Where can I download ActivePerl PPM .zip's or .ppd's? I can't find them anywhere.

Tags: mongodb, perl, perl-module, activeperl

I need to download ActivePerl PPM .zips or .ppd's so I can install the MongoDB perl driver on machines that do not have an internet connection. The problem is that all of the links I find in documentation don't point anywhere that lets me download .zip's or .ppd's. They just point me to more documentation that tells me about the modules. I think ActivePerl might have changed their site.

Does anyone know where I can download these?

I've had no problems downloading and installing with the PPM tool on machines that do have an internet connection. Also, this is a possible solution, but I can't use CPAN (I've already created a minicpan and the MongoDB CPAN module only works with strawberry perl - I can't compile it with MSVC with cpan or manually).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MongoDB 0.42 for [ActivePerl 5.10](http://ppm4.activestate.com/MSWin32-x86/5.10/1000/K/KR/KRISTINA/MongoDB-0.42.tar.gz) and
[ActivePerl 5.12](http://ppm4.activestate.com/MSWin32-x86/5.12/1200/K/KR/KRISTINA/MongoDB-0.42.tar.gz).

To find those URLs, I just looked through the `packages.xml` file from the [5.10](http://ppm4.activestate.com/MSWin32-x86/5.10/1000/) and [5.12](http://ppm4.activestate.com/MSWin32-x86/5.12/1200/) repository pages.

Comment: thanks, i can't believe it - i must have missed those when looking through the xml file...